# Рекурсивный роутинг React + react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Всем привет. Изучая новую версию react-router-dom(rrd) я увидел, что появилась возможность вложенных роутов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал сделать систему роутинга с объектом ROUTES, в котором были бы параметры, необходимые для Route из rrd + всякие доп свойства. Вот этот объект:

```
export const ROUTES: IRoute[] = [
{
    path: paths.HOME,
    element: Map,
    children: [
        {
            path: paths.ADMIN,
            element: Admin,
        },
        {
            path: 'test1',
            element: Admin,
        },
        {
            path: 'test2',
            element: Admin,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 't2test1',
                    element: Admin,
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
},];
```

В итоге, я хотел сделать рекурсивный компонент, которой бы принимал один роут, создавал его, а потом внутри себя создавал дочерние(те что в свойстве children) роуты. И я, вроде, сделал, но мне выдает ошибку. Не до конца понимаю, как это исправить.

```
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import {Route as R} from 'react-router-dom';

import {IRoute} from "./routes";


interface RouteProps {
    route: IRoute;
}

const Route: FC<RouteProps> = ({route}) => {
    return (
        <R
            index={route.index}
            path={route.path}
            element={<route.element/>}
        >
            {route.children?.map(r => <Route route={r}/>)}
        </R>
    );
};

export default Route;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кажется, вы не используете [контекст](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/57407d3d1ee33b26874329f23383352d1de442a4/docs/faq.md#how-do-i-nest-routes-deep-in-the-tree)

Comment: Я, вроде как, посмотрел, но все равно не до конца понимаю, что мне нужно исправить. Выше, над Route, я использую BrowserRouter и Routes